# bcrypt not installing when tried to using npm i bcrypt

Tags: node.js, npm, bcrypt, mosh

I am getting error Cannot find module 'bcrypt' in nodejs application

I have tried to install it using npm install bcrypt but still getting the issue

```
npm i bcrypt
```

[image]

Comment: Did you install the Destkop development with C++ workloard as suggested following the link ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is trying to build `bcrypt` from source, but you don't have the necessary tools installed for it to do so.

Try installing the Visual C++ Build Tools first, which can be done using the following convenience npm package:

```sh
npm install -g windows-build-tools
```

Once that is complete, run `npm install bcrypt` again.

More info here: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-build-tools